# How could the "unhackabilty" of quantum Internet justify its cost?

Tags: network, cryptography

The U.S. Department of Energy (DOE) seems to be [very excited](https://www.energy.gov/articles/us-department-energy-unveils-blueprint-quantum-internet-launch-future-quantum-internet) about the potential of a quantum Internet:

> One of the hallmarks of quantum transmissions is that they are exceedingly difficult to eavesdrop on as information passes between locations. Scientists plan to use that trait to make virtually unhackable networks. Early adopters could include industries such as banking and health services, with applications for national security and aircraft communications. Eventually, **the use of quantum networking technology in mobile phones could have broad impacts on the lives of individuals around the world**. [...] the quantum internet could become a secure communications network and have a profound impact on areas critical to science, industry, and national security.

What problem exactly is the quantum Internet trying to solve? Is it a current problem or a future problem? As far as I could tell, the press release doesn't say. Is it an implied problem?

---

So quantum transmissions would reveal if they were read in transit before the intended recipient, which would preclude MitM attacks. But so does TLS, and even though MitM attacks against TLS are possible, the vast majority of attacks are conducted not against data in transit, but against data at rest, OS and hardware vulnerabilities, and most commonly (between [80%](https://www.csoonline.com/article/3153707/top-cybersecurity-facts-figures-and-statistics.html) and [98%](https://purplesec.us/resources/cyber-security-statistics/), depending on [which](https://www.varonis.com/blog/cybersecurity-statistics/) statistics you look at), via social engineering. I've looked at several cybersecurity stats, and the bottom line is that the vast majority of attacks are [due to human error](https://www.cybintsolutions.com/cyber-security-facts-stats/).

Could quantum-secure transmissions help in any way mitigate the types of cyberattacks we've been seeing in the past 10 years, and which are likely to continue? "Early adopters could include industries such as banking" - how much has banking been affected by insecure Internet *links* (rather than hosts or persons)?

Or does the press release completely gloss over something else - that quantum *computers* (rather than the quantum Internet) would be able to break current public key crypotography, hence a quantum Internet would be useful to prevent *those* future attacks? Is that it, and a case of a vague press release, or am I neglecting something else?

As a commenter mentioned, how would QI justify the hugely expensive QKD backed links, vs. using the much cheaper Post-Quantum-Cryptography?

I'm also failing to understand how "the use of quantum networking technology in mobile phones could have **broad impacts on the lives of individuals around the world**". The vast majority of mobile phone users are completely oblivious to the security of their communications, and they wouldn't behave any differently if they thought their communications were completely secure.

Comment: "But so does TLS" -- no it doesn't. TLS protects the transmission from being understood when it is read. You have also missed the scope and context of the quote: "unhackable networks". It does not say "unhackable devices" or "unhackable people". You are expanding the scope to suggest that this might be a silver bullet for all types of issues.

Comment: You are missing the context and you do not appear to understand the problem that this solves. *With* quantum computers, there *will* be attacks directly on the encrypted transmissions. Trying to apply a solution for a different context to an old context will only result in confusion.

Comment: This is not about post-quantum as your tag suggests, i.e. not about cryptography and communication safe against quantum computers. This is about using quantum effects for secure communication, i.e. QKD (Quantum Key Distribution). Also, just by proposing that the main security problem are the users anyway you basically question already the need of TLS and other current use of cryptography. Still, the question remains what the advantage of hugely expensive QKD backed links is instead of using the much cheaper Post-Quantum-Cryptography.

Comment: It's thought that quantum computers will break most (all?) existing public key crypto. This motivates research on replacements. But I agree, the benefits here are hyperbole.

Comment: You're title also does not match the body. How is "cost" a factor?

Comment: Thanks @SteffenUllrich and everyone esle for the feedback. I've updated the question and the tags.

Comment: "What problem does quantum internet solve?" Have you looked beyond the press release? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_network#Secure_communications

Comment: @schroeder: I tried to take the press release at face value, because given its style, I don't think it assumes that the reader has much knowledge about quantum computing. The *Secure communications* heading (and its parent "Applications" heading) from the Wikipedia page don't discuss how, or in which applications with "broad impacts on the lives of individuals around the world", quantum networks would justify their cost, vs. traditional secure communications.

Comment: I'm closing for a few reasons. First, it lacks focus, second, you are basically asking what a quantum network *does*, which is simple to look up (it even has a wiki page), third, you explicitly state that you have not done any research on your own and your question is based entirely on a press release, fourth, you are asking the community to justify the DoE's *press release*, fifth you are also asking for an opinion about the cost/benefit about something that the article explicitly states won't even exist for a decade.

Comment: So, in short, you have arbitrarily constrained the discussion, not done any research, and asked an opinion-based question about *cost* without any data about costs. What it appears you really want to ask is "is it all worth it?", which is unanswerable.

Comment: @schroeder So in short, I should throw myself out the security.SE's ivory tower window :)

Comment: Just ask a logical, well-formed, answerable question. No ivory tower here. If you want to poll for opinions, there's always Reddit.